# How can I manually figure out stack variable/buffer sizes from stripped x86-64 disassembly?

Tags: ida, disassembly, ghidra, decompiler

I am looking at the following CTF challenge:

```
 0x56555779 <+0>:   lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x5655577d <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x56555780 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x56555783 <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x56555784 <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x56555786 <+13>:    push   ebx
   0x56555787 <+14>:    push   ecx
   0x56555788 <+15>:    sub    esp,0x40
   0x5655578b <+18>:    call   0x56555600 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
   0x56555790 <+23>:    add    ebx,0x1820
   0x56555796 <+29>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebx+0x44]
   0x5655579c <+35>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x5655579e <+37>:    push   0x0
   0x565557a0 <+39>:    push   0x0
   0x565557a2 <+41>:    push   0x2
   0x565557a4 <+43>:    push   eax
   0x565557a5 <+44>:    call   0x56555580 <setvbuf@plt>
   0x565557aa <+49>:    add    esp,0x10
=> 0x565557ad <+52>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x2
   0x565557b4 <+59>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],0x0
   0x565557bb <+66>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x565557be <+69>:    lea    eax,[ebx-0x1620]
   0x565557c4 <+75>:    push   eax
   0x565557c5 <+76>:    call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x565557ca <+81>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x565557cd <+84>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x565557d0 <+87>:    lea    eax,[ebx-0x15b5]
   0x565557d6 <+93>:    push   eax
   0x565557d7 <+94>:    call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x565557dc <+99>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x565557df <+102>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebx+0x40]
   0x565557e5 <+108>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x565557e7 <+110>:   sub    esp,0x4
   0x565557ea <+113>:   push   eax
   0x565557eb <+114>:   push   0x2b
   0x565557ed <+116>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x3b]
   0x565557f0 <+119>:   push   eax
   0x565557f1 <+120>:   call   0x56555530 <fgets@plt>
   0x565557f6 <+125>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x565557f9 <+128>:   sub    esp,0x8
   0x565557fc <+131>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x159f]
   0x56555802 <+137>:   push   eax
   0x56555803 <+138>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x3b]
   0x56555806 <+141>:   push   eax
   0x56555807 <+142>:   call   0x56555510 <strcmp@plt>
   0x5655580c <+147>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x5655580f <+150>:   test   eax,eax
   0x56555811 <+152>:   je     0x5655582f <main+182>
   0x56555813 <+154>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x56555816 <+157>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x1584]
   0x5655581c <+163>:   push   eax
   0x5655581d <+164>:   call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x56555822 <+169>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x56555825 <+172>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x56555828 <+175>:   push   0x0
   0x5655582a <+177>:   call   0x56555560 <exit@plt>
   0x5655582f <+182>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x56555832 <+185>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x1564]
   0x56555838 <+191>:   push   eax
   0x56555839 <+192>:   call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x5655583e <+197>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x56555841 <+200>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebx+0x40]
   0x56555847 <+206>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x56555849 <+208>:   sub    esp,0x4
   0x5655584c <+211>:   push   eax
   0x5655584d <+212>:   push   0x2b
   0x5655584f <+214>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x3b]
   0x56555852 <+217>:   push   eax
   0x56555853 <+218>:   call   0x56555530 <fgets@plt>
   0x56555858 <+223>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x5655585b <+226>:   sub    esp,0x8
   0x5655585e <+229>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x154d]
   0x56555864 <+235>:   push   eax
   0x56555865 <+236>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x3b]
   0x56555868 <+239>:   push   eax
   0x56555869 <+240>:   call   0x56555510 <strcmp@plt>
   0x5655586e <+245>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x56555871 <+248>:   test   eax,eax
   0x56555873 <+250>:   je     0x56555891 <main+280>
   0x56555875 <+252>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x56555878 <+255>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x1584]
   0x5655587e <+261>:   push   eax
   0x5655587f <+262>:   call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x56555884 <+267>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x56555887 <+270>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x5655588a <+273>:   push   0x0
   0x5655588c <+275>:   call   0x56555560 <exit@plt>
   0x56555891 <+280>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x56555894 <+283>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x1534]
   0x5655589a <+289>:   push   eax
   0x5655589b <+290>:   call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x565558a0 <+295>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x565558a3 <+298>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x565558a6 <+301>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x3b]
   0x565558a9 <+304>:   push   eax
   0x565558aa <+305>:   call   0x56555520 <gets@plt>
   0x565558af <+310>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x565558b2 <+313>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],0xdea110c8
   0x565558b9 <+320>:   jne    0x565558c2 <main+329>
   0x565558bb <+322>:   call   0x565556fd <print_flag>
   0x565558c0 <+327>:   jmp    0x565558d4 <main+347>
   0x565558c2 <+329>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x565558c5 <+332>:   lea    eax,[ebx-0x1584]
   0x565558cb <+338>:   push   eax
   0x565558cc <+339>:   call   0x56555550 <puts@plt>
   0x565558d1 <+344>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x565558d4 <+347>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x565558d9 <+352>:   lea    esp,[ebp-0x8]
   0x565558dc <+355>:   pop    ecx
   0x565558dd <+356>:   pop    ebx
   0x565558de <+357>:   pop    ebp
   0x565558df <+358>:   lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x565558e2 <+361>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Ghidra decompiler shows me this:

```
{
  int iVar1;
  char user_buf [43];
  int overwrite_me;
  undefined4 local_14;
  undefined *local_10;
  
  local_10 = &stack0x00000004;
  setvbuf(stdout,(char *)0x2,0,0);
  local_14 = 2;
  overwrite_me = 0;
  puts(
        "Stop! Who would cross the Bridge of Death must answer me these questions three, ere the other  side he see."
        );
  puts("What... is your name?");
  fgets(user_buf,0x2b,stdin);
  iVar1 = strcmp(user_buf,"Sir Lancelot of Camelot\n");
  if (iVar1 != 0) {
     puts("I don\'t know that! Auuuuuuuugh!");
                            /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
     exit(0);
  }
  puts("What... is your quest?");
  fgets(user_buf,0x2b,stdin);
  iVar1 = strcmp(user_buf,"To seek the Holy Grail.\n");
  if (iVar1 != 0) {
     puts("I don\'t know that! Auuuuuuuugh!");
                            /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
     exit(0);
  }
  puts("What... is my secret?");
  gets(user_buf);
  if (overwrite_me == -0x215eef38) {
     print_flag();
  }
  else {
     puts("I don\'t know that! Auuuuuuuugh!");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Ok, some of those vars I obviously named, but the decompiler knows that there's an int, followed by a 43-byte char buffer, followed by an int up at the top of the function. How do decompilers and disassemblers learn this info? By looking at the disassembly in `gdb`, I do not know that the buffer is 43 bytes for example because there is a single `sub esp, 0x40` instruction, which overs all of that in one motion. However, I can infer the size based on these instructions:

```
   0x565557eb <+114>:   push   0x2b
   0x565557ed <+116>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x3b]
```

However, in some situations, it may not be that obvious.

NOTE: I am not trying to solve this challenge, I've already solved it - this is a curiosity/educational question.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to be a master of "big questions", thats why I reverse. :)